# by the age of vs at the age of

Tags: meaning-in-context

"By the age of ten, Thorleif was keeping detailed notebooks, which he maintained for years."

Does this sentence mean that Thorleif stopped keeping detailed notebooks when he reached the age of ten or he started keeping them when he reached the age of ten. I'm confused.

Thanks,

Comment: It means he *started* keeping notebooks because what the sentence implies is: ***"By (the time he reached) the age of ten, Thorleif was keeping detailed notebooks."***  If he had stopped at the age of 10, it would have said: ***"Up until the age of 10, Thorleif had been keeping detailed notebooks."*** This type of preposition-usage question might be better off on the English Language Learners site: http://ELL.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

By the age:  At the time of reaching the age he was already performing this function.

At the age:  He began in the same year as reaching the age.

Neither implies stopping in any manner.

That would be *up until the age*, meaning he was performing the function and stopped upon reaching that age.

Comment: Sometimes it is confusing because one of the meanings of by is before or until(during the period until a particular time or date. Tale a look at the sentence below:By the time Charlotte was 15, she had already achieved worldwide fame.

Comment: One of the meanings of by is before or until. "By the time Charlotte was 15, she had already achieved fame." Here it is so obvious that we talk about a time period before she reached 15. As to my sentence, first I thought it means until he reached the age of ten, he was keeping detailed notebooks and at the age of 10, she stopped doing it. Apparently I am wrong and now I see two possibilities: 1- He may have started them before the age of ten 2- He started writing them when he exactly reached the age of ten, not before that. I want to make sure that I got this correct. Thanks for your help:-)

Comment: @fate Yes, English has a fair number of subtle usages.  And, the shorter the phrase, sometimes the harder to figure out its meaning.